# Would resizing a running EMR cluster speeds up the execution of the existing running job

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mapreduce, emr

I am running an EMR cluster with 25 nodes and a job is running on for continuously 15-20 minutes. I realized that it would take another 30-40 minutes so I added 10 more task nodes in the cluster. But I didn't see any improvement.

Would adding these extra task nodes increase the concurrent mappers execution in current job or the extra nodes will be used for only the jobs initiated after resizing?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the MapReduce job is structured. If there was tasks pending then the additional nodes will be used. If the job determined its number of tasks based on original size of the cluster then additional nodes will not make a difference until new job submission.

Comment: The calculation of number of tasks is always done beforehand. That's why the console always shows you the counters against number of successful, pending and running tasks.

Comment: What I mean is that some jobs match the number of MapReduce tasks to the max concurrent tasks possible. In that case adding nodes will not make any difference.

Comment: For that case, it makes sense. 
But are you sure for pending tasks, EMR will schedule them to new task nodes? I didn't see an performance improvement while running my EMR job though.